# Transforming from scaled value back to original scale

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to transform a predicted scaled value back to its original scale. Here is the code that I've used till now:

```
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('sbs_selector', SBSFeatureSelector(sbs.subsets_, k=5)),
    ('lineReg', LinearRegression())
])
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_val_pred = pipe.predict(X_val)
test=pd.read_csv('./Kaggle-Bike-Sharing-Demand-Challenge/test.csv')
X_test = test.iloc[:,1:]
y_pred_log = pipe.predict(X_test)

y_pred = ......
```

Now, I want to transform back to original scale and integer values and store it in `y_pred`. How can I do this?

Comment: Every scaler in sklearn has `inverse_transform` method so if you take it out from pipeline and perform operations separately you could do `unscaled_data = pipe.inverse_transform(data)` You could refer to documetation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html

Comment: I tried y_pred = pipe.inverse_transform(y_pred_log) but I'm getting error : AttributeError: 'SBSFeatureSelector' object has no attribute 'inverse_transform'

Comment: Ah my bad. Not pipe but need to perform scaler, model one by one without using pipeline then you could do `std_scaler.inverse_transform`

Comment: Please can you let me know how I can do it in current code? And I don't want to remove pipeline

Comment: Not sure if there is a way to do it inside pipeline. You could take out only scaler or if you don't want to do that just fit new scaler for inverse transform purposes.

Comment: The `StandardScaler` does not scale the target variable.  Using the name `y_pred_log` suggests you may have log-transformed your target, but you haven't provided that code.  If it was just log-transformed, then you can exponentiate it.  Otherwise, we need more information.  (Have a look at `TransformedTargetRegressor` too.)